# Can I send text using S-voice through Google Voice?

Tags: sms, google-voice, s-voice

I have a Galaxy S 3. Can I send an SMS using Google Voice using S-voice (like I can natively)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will be able to send a SMS with S-Voice.